# Adding a custom search for a classic report

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to add a search to my classic report so I added a textbox and a button on my page, above the report and I added a process to the page, executing PL/SQL code:

```
DECLARE
    v_sql varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
IF :P3_SEARCH IS NOT NULL THEN
    v_sql := q'[select field1, field2, field3
           FROM Table1
           WHERE category_id = ]' ||TO_NUMBER(:P3_CATEGORY)||
           q'[ AND (function(id) LIKE '%]'||:P3_SEARCH||| 
           q'[%' OR field2 LIKE '%]' ||:P3_SEARCH|| 
           q'[%' OR field3 LIKE '%]' ||:P3_SEARCH|| q'[%')]';
ELSE
    v_sql := q'[select field1, field2, field3
           FROM Table1
           WHERE category_id = ]' ||TO_NUMBER(:P3_CATEGORY)|| q'[]';
    END IF;

  apex_debug.MESSAGE('my query is: ' || v_sql);      

    --   RETURN v_sql;
END;
```

I have two issues - my resulting query does not come out as expected - `%` signs disappear and instead of

```
select field1, field2, field3
FROM Table1
WHERE category_id = 4
AND (function(id) like '%test%' OR field2 like '%test%' OR field3 like '%test%')
```

I get

```
select field1, field2, field3
FROM Table1
WHERE category_id = 4
AND (function(id) like 'test' OR field2 like 'test' OR field3 like 'test')
```

And I also cannot figure out how do I switch the source sql for my report region when the search button is clicked. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be dynamic? Because, there's nothing *dynamic* in that query. If it is the `:P3_SEARCH` that bothers you, then there's a way out. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
select something
from some_table
where some_column = :P3_SEARCH        --> condition A
   or :P3_SEARCH is null;             --> condition B
```

Expanded to your query, it could be rewritten as follows:

```
select field1, field2, field3
from table1
where category_id = to_number(:P3_CATEGORY)
  and (  
         --> condition A begins here
         -- condition for P3_SEARCH is not null
        (     :P3_SEARCH is not null
          and(   function(id) like '%' || :P3_SEARCH || '%'
              or field2       like '%' || :P3_SEARCH || '%'
              or field3       like '%' || :P3_SEARCH || '%'
             )
        )
        --> condition A ends here  
      or :P3_SEARCH is null        --> condition B
     );
```

See if it helps.